# How can i change the cursor color in react-native?

Tags: react-native

[image]

I'm trying to change the pointer of cursor but i don't have sucess.

I have managed to change color selection, but I want to change the pointer where in the image below is green. Can someone help me?

Answer (score 1):

For Android I think the property is in styles.xml, try setting it there:

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light">
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/kio_turquoise</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/kio_hot_pink</item>

    <!-- sets cursor color -->
    <item name="colorControlActivated">@android:color/blue</item>
 </style>
```

Comment: Thanks man. This solve my problem. 
    <style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
        <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
        <item name="colorControlActivated">#F6CB3E</item>
    </style>